# WSO2 1.7 - "Try It" Doesn't work

Tags: javascript, wso2, wso2-api-manager

Saw other questions/answers from September and still not having any success. I'm having the same issue described in the original post, when hitting the "Try It" button, dots flash in lower right corner, but never get a response, even if no authorization key is listed or no parameters provided. Both FireFox and Chrome are doing the same thing. I tried updating the CORS configuration as described in the earlier post, restarted the server, and had no effect. I used Firebug and saw the following in the console:

```
Blocked loading mixed active content "...localhost:8280/phoneverify/1.1.0?PhoneNumber=18008765432&LicenseKey=0"

...l = xml.replace(reg, '$1\n$2$3').replace(wsexp, '$1\n').replace(contexp, '$1\n$2...

swagger-ui.js (line 1624)
```

Any ideas what I might need to do?

Comment: Please at least link that original post you are referring to.

Answer (score 0):

Set your API Store URLs in The CORS Configurations and restart the server. 
Add OPTIONS HTTP verb into your API resources with 'None' Authentication Type.
Try-it your API in chrome browser. 
If your backend supports OPTIONS method, then this should work.

If it didn't work check if there is any errors in the browser. Main errors can be,

- API not supporting OPTIONS method for currently trying resource with
  'None' Authentication Type.
- Backend not supporting OPTIONS method.
- API Store address which you are currently trying swagger is not
  included in the CORS configuration.
- Browser blocking.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, and sorry for the delay getting back.  As another poster pointed out, I failed to provide the URL of the post I referenced, here it is:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25483556/try-it-now-in-the-quick-start-never-returns  Per the previous post, I updated my CORS configuration in api-manager.xml so that it now says:  <Access-Control-Allow-Origin>https://localhost:9443,http://localhost:9763,http://localhost:8280</Access-Conrol-Allow-Origin>  Otherwise, I just followed the instructions in the QuickStart guide as mentioned in the post I referenced.

Comment: In addition, I am using the Chrome browser and even found a way to start the browser with an argument that disables all security, and had the same results.  From your answer I was looking at the API section in api-manager.xml, but wasn't exactly sure what you were suggesting, and what other parameters I might need to define the API.  I appreciate any additional help you can provide.